# How to take graphics drawn in the UIView and save as a jpg or something else on the iPhone to pull up in the "Photos"?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How to take graphics drawn in the UIView and save as a jpg or something on the iPhone to pull up in the "Photos" and or attach to an email?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward to get a UIImage:

```
UIImage* image = nil;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_myView.frame.size);
{
    [_myView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then [save to the photos library with this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum):

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_myView, ,